# List who attended an MS Teams meeting and for how long they attended

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'd like to list who attended a MS Teams meeting and for how long they attended so they can get credit for attending a training session.

I've looked at the Graph API v1 and beta versions. Meetings have an object called `meetingParticipantInfo`, but there's nothing that I've seen that would indicate if that participant actually attended the meeting. Is there a way to get this information, and ideally, how long the participant attended? Or is there another way to get this information through bots?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/meetingparticipants?view=graph-rest-beta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [Feb 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog#february-2020), Microsoft Graph API now includes [microsoft.graph.callRecords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) (beta, preview).

If you call with session information expanded you can get `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` of each session which is the "time when the first user joined the session" and the "time when the last user left the session" respectively.

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/{id}?$expand=sessions($expand=segments)`

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-session?view=graph-rest-beta) the documentation for the call record session fields.

Comment: Hi Micah   
What is {id} in the GET API?     
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/{id}
From where I can get this {id}.

Comment: you cannot get a list of callRecords I think. The way we I get them is through a webhook (subscription)

Answer (score 4):

The (CDR's) Call Detail Records are probably the information your looking for as they should contain that information see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams-Blog/Microsoft-Teams-launches-eDiscovery-for-Calling-and-Meetings/ba-p/210947 . I don't believe any of the Graph API's will surface that information but you can get the raw information from a Mailbox using EWS this is what I use https://dev.to/gscales/accessing-microsoft-teams-summary-records-cdr-s-for-calls-and-meetings-using-exchange-web-services-3581 . If you use a tool like mfcMapi https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi/releases you can browse the Mailbox to see if a CDR is available and has the information you need without needing to write any code.

Comment: Do you know if this can be done outside a company network, like the way Graph API is accessed?

Answer (score 0):

You should vote for this feature : https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/33989875-view-or-export-a-list-of-users-who-attended-a-meet

Then you can try with this : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/microsoft-teams-launches-ediscovery-for-calling-and-meetings/ba-p/210947

I try to develop an app calling the Graph API, so if I do success, I will share it ;-)

Comment: We encourage linking to external sources but we have zero control over edits or if that site exists in 10 years or 10 minutes. Consequently, we also need the most relevant content in the answers. If you can put it in and @ me I'll upvote your answer. If you don't you will see some down votes for this. "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." See "Provide context for links" in the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) article here. ;-)