# Track Attendance to MS Teams Call

Tags: python, powershell, powerbi, microsoft-teams, power-automate

We are looking to track attendance to show reach as well as accountability of certain global calls. Currently, we manually track attendance to global calls by hand by designating someone to check an "attendance sheet" in Excel marking everyone either abset or present.

Obviously we want to avoid manual steps wherever possible and it's not a perfect science since people come and go thru the meetings sometimes.  Is there a way to use Python, PowerShell, Microsoft Flow (PowerAutomate) or any other tracking method to log this data for us?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some information given regarding tracking meeting attendance in MS Call. Hope this helps.
[List who attended an MS Teams meeting and for how long they attended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59146742/list-who-attended-an-ms-teams-meeting-and-for-how-long-they-attended)